# task scheduler on Windows Server 2012 just runs by selecting "Run" (.bat)

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2012

I want to run a .bat file from my windows server 2012 in a task schedule. After i setted up everything, the task schedule doesn't run byself. it works if i rightclick the task and klick "Run", so the .bat file and the action setings have to be correct.On general settings i have selected "regardless if logged in" and "run with highest privileges" and the user group contains "Serverdirectory"/Admnistrator (by defaullt) . The schedule is running as administrator so i have all privileges. would be great getting some help.

### EDIT

the scheduler logs

> The request was rejected by the operator or administrator

So i think there are some access/privileg issues. Somehow the System is blocking the task scheduler. Does someone know which setting to change or where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works now. I changed the tasks directory. It was the "Windows" directory before.... so i think i havent got the privileges to run scheduled tasks from there.